# How to parse reserved words correctly in boost spirit

Tags: parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to parse a sequence of the syntax: < direction > < type > < name >.  For example:

```
in float foo
```

where the direction can be either **in**, **out**, or **in_out**.  I've succeeded in parsing correct text by using a qi::symbols class to convert the direction keywords to an enum.

However, the problem shows when I don't have correct text.  Take the example:

```
int foo
```

The symbol table parser will except the 'in' part of the 'int' type and so the results will be:

```
direction: in
type: t
name: foo
```

And the error is not detected.  What's the best way to be able to parse the in, out and in_out reserved words and ensure that they are followed by a non-identifier character so that the 'int' part of the previous text fails?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the "manual" approach suggested by Mike you can

1. use a convenience wrapper rule
2. use the `distinct` parser direetive from the Spirit Repository

### 1. Use a convenience wrapper

I just remembered, I once came up with this quick and dirty helper:

```
static const qi::rule<It, qi::unused_type(const char*)> kw 
      = qi::lit(qi::_r1) >> !qi::alnum;
```

Which you could use like (using `+"lit"` to decay the array-ref into `const char*`):

```
stmt = 
         kw(+"if") >> '(' >> expr >> ')' >> block
     >> -(kw(+"else") >> block)
     ;
```

You can make it considerably more convenient

```
template <std::size_t N>
static auto kw(char const (&keyword)[N]) -> qi::rule<Iterator> {
    // qi::lit has problems with char arrays, use pointer instead.
    return qi::lit(+keyword) >> !qi::alnum;
}
```

So you can

```
kw_if   = kw("if");
kw_then = kw("then");
kw_else = kw("else");
kw_and  = kw("and");
kw_or   = kw("or");
kw_not  = kw("not");
```

### 2. Use the `distinct` directive from the Spirit Repository

In addition to the "manual" approach suggested by Mike you can use the `distinct` parser directive from the Spirit Repository:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/repository/test/qi/distinct.cpp

```
int main()
{
    using namespace spirit_test;
    using namespace boost::spirit;

    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;

        qi::rule<char const*, space_type> r;
        r = distinct::keyword["description"] >> -lit(':') >> distinct::keyword["ident"];

        BOOST_TEST(test("description ident", r, space));
        BOOST_TEST(test("description:ident", r, space));
        BOOST_TEST(test("description: ident", r, space));
        BOOST_TEST(!test("descriptionident", r, space));
    }

    return boost::report_errors();
}
```

Comment: But I would rather use a symbol table to map the keywords to values (which I store as an enum in an AST).  This method would require me to write action semantics on every check?  Could I wrap distinct::keyword around a symbol table parser?

Comment: Of course! Have you, like, tried it? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6956a8e9c18553d2

Comment: And, just for fun, here's the `kw()` approach to the `symbols` parser: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c949b4cd44f3c20e

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I'm busy with other stuff right now but I will test it out and get back to you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the and predicate or the not predicate parser, depending on what you would like to express. The predicate parsers just check the next symbols but don't consume them.

This says, you expect a blank (space or tab) afterwards:

```
rule = symbol_parser >> &qi::blank;
```

This says, you don't want to have a letter, number or underscore afterwards:

```
rule = symbol_parser >> !(qi::alnum | qi::lit("_"));
```

Comment: +1 and there are ways (in the Spirit code base) to automate that