# Pass symbol table as inherited attribute to boost spirit rule

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have a couple of symbol tables on which I want to inhibit partial matching.

Reading across some questions, I figured it can be done using the `distinct directive`.

However, adding `distinct(char_("a-zAZ09_"))[no_case[my_symb_1]];` each time a symbol table is referenced in the grammar is reducing readability. So I tried to make a rule that accepts a symbol table and returns its matching value:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, Operation(const qi::symbols<char, Operation>&)> no_partial_match;

no_partial_match %= distinct(char_("a-zAZ09_"))[no_case[lazy(_r1)]];
```

And use it later in the grammar:

```
some_rule = no_partial_match(my_symb_1) >> int_;
```

but it fails with:

```
    const boost::spirit::qi::symbols<char,Operation,boost::spirit::qi::tst<Char,T>,boost::spirit::qi::tst_pass_through>::adder
 &boost::spirit::qi::symbols<Char,T,boost::spirit::qi::tst<Char,T>,boost::spirit::qi::tst_pass_through>::adder::operator
 ()(const Iterator &,const Iterator &,const T &) const': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
```

How to achieve this?

(*PS: I'm aware of the generic solution provided in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131162/how-to-parse-reserved-words-correctly-in-boost-spirit), but I'm looking for a simpler approach for this specific symbol table signature and not a generic one.*)

Answer (score 1):

Got it, has to wrap the symbol table in `phx::ref(...)`

like this

```
some_rule = no_partial_match(phx::ref(my_symb_1)) >> int_;
```