# Boost.Qi rule with skipper does not match '.' character

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, qi

So I have the following qi skipper:

```
template<typename Iterator> struct verilog_skipper :
public qi::grammar<Iterator> {

verilog_skipper() : verilog_skipper::base_type(skip) {
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
    skip = qi::ascii::space | qi::eol | line_comment;
    line_comment = (qi::lit("//") >> *(qi::char_ - qi::eol) >> *(qi::eol));
}
qi::rule<Iterator> skip;
qi::rule<Iterator> line_comment;
};
```

and the following qi grammar:

```
template <typename Iterator, 
typename Skipper = verilog_skipper<Iterator> struct verilog_grammer : 
qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper> {
verilog_ast ckt_ast;

verilog_grammer()
: verilog_grammer::base_type(module) {

namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

module = (module_definition >> statements >> qi::lit("endmodule"));

statements = statement % ';';

statement = (input_wires | instance);

module_definition = (qi::lit("module") >> ident >> qi::char_('(')
                >> ident_list >>  qi::char_(')') >> ';' );

input_wires = (qi::lit("input") >> ident_list);

instance = (ident >> ident >> 
qi::char_('(') >> connection_pair_list >> qi::char_(')'));

connection_pair_list = connection_pair % ',';
connection_pair =  (qi::char_('.')[phx::bind(&found_smth)] 
>> ident >> qi::char_('(') >> ident >> qi::char_(')'));

ident_list = ident % ',';
ident = (qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9"));
}

qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> module;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> module_definition;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> statements;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> statement;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> instance;
qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> input_wires;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >(), Skipper> connection_pair_list;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(), Skipper> connection_pair;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), Skipper> ident_list;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> ident;
};
```

I have binded the `found_smth` function to the dot character in the grammar. I feel the rules are correct but I am unable to match any connection_pairs in the following input and the parse fails as the iterators do not reach one another:

```
module mymod (A, B);

input A, B;

XOR21 gatexor5 (.A(B) , .C(D));
endmodule
```

Is the skipper consuming the dot? I should get a match on the dot immediately right? Can anyone help me spot the issue?

Here is my `main` code:

```
typedef verilog_skipper<std::string::const_iterator> verilog_skipper;
typedef verilog_grammer<std::string::const_iterator, verilog_skipper> verilog_grammar;
verilog_grammar vg; // Our grammar
verilog_skipper vg_skip; // Our grammar

using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
std::string::const_iterator iter = storage.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end = storage.end();

bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, vg, vg_skip);

if (r && iter == end)
{
  std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
  std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
  std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I have heard that qi::ascii::space can consume not just spaces"  - just say no to magical thinking.

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

1. You need to brush up on skippers and lexemes:

   - [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)
2. Specifically, `qi::eol` is part of `qi::space` (not `qi::blank`). I'd specify the skipper simply as

   ```
   skip = qi::ascii::space | line_comment;
   line_comment = "//" >> *(qi::char_ - qi::eol) >> (qi::eol|qi::eoi);
   ```
3. Even more specifically, you'll /need/ to make sure identifiers are a lexeme. The simplest way is to drop the skipper from the rule's declaration. Otherwise `"a b\nc"` is a perfectly valid spelling of the identifier `"abc"`.

   ```
   // lexemes
   qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> primitive_gate, ident;
   ```
4. Next up your sample shows **every** statement terminated with `';'`. But your grammar says:

   ```
   statements = statement % ';';
   ```

   This will allow `"S1"`, `"S1;S2"`, ... but *not* `"S1;"`. There are several ways to fix it. The simplest would appear to be

   ```
   statements = +(statement >> ';'); // require exactly one `;` always
   ```

   Alternatively, if `"S1;;;;"` is also acceptable, you might be tempted to say

   ```
   statements = +(statement >> +qi::lit(';')); // require at least one `;` always
   ```

   Note though that this would **not** accept `";;;S1;;"`, nor `""` as you might have expected. A pattern I often employ is the optional element list:

   ```
   statements = -statement % ';'; // simple and flexible
   ```

   Which has a nice way of accepting `""`, `";"`, `";;"`, `"S1"`, `";;S1;"` etc. Note it's **not** as efficient as something more verbose like

   ```
   statements = *(*qi::lit(';') >> statement >> +qi::lit(';')); // require exactly one `;` always
   ```
5. I note you use `qi::char_('(')` (and similar) that will expose the matched character in the synthesized attribute. It is ***highly unlikely*** this is what you mean. Use `qi::lit('(')` instead, or indeed, using bare character/string literals in your parser expression will promote them to parser expressions¹
6. Consider using BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG to gain insight into what your grammar is doing
7. Encapsulate your skipper, since the caller should not be bothered about it, and you likely do not want users of your grammar to be able to change the skipper (that might break the entire grammar).
8. Consider using symbols instead of listing keywords, like:

   ```
   primitive_gate       = qi::lit("nand") | "nor" | "and" | "or" | "xor" |
       "xnor" | "buf" | "not";
   ```
9. Pay attention to the ordering and keyword matching. If you parse an identifier, a keyword like `nand` would match. If you have an identifier like `xor21` however, the keyword `xor` would match first. You may want/need to guard against this ([How to parse reserved words correctly in boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131162/how-to-parse-reserved-words-correctly-in-boost-spirit/20133011#20133011))
10. Note that the presence of a semantic action (like e.g. the `found_smth`) *inhibits* automatic attribute propagation, unless you use `operator%=` to assign the parser expression to the rule.

### DEMO TIME

Applying the above...:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yk7CULLwRkBMG2g9)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_distinct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

static void found_smth() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

template <typename Iterator> struct verilog_skipper : qi::grammar<Iterator> {

    verilog_skipper() : verilog_skipper::base_type(skip) {
        skip = qi::ascii::space | line_comment;
        line_comment = "//" >> *(qi::char_ - qi::eol) >> (qi::eol|qi::eoi);
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator> skip;
    qi::rule<Iterator> line_comment;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct verilog_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator> {
    //verilog_ast ckt_ast;
    typedef verilog_skipper<Iterator> Skipper;

    verilog_grammar() : verilog_grammar::base_type(start) {

        namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
        using boost::spirit::repository::qi::distinct;
        auto kw = distinct(qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9"));

        start                = qi::skip(qi::copy(skipper)) [module];
        module               = (module_definition >> statements >> kw["endmodule"]);

        module_definition    = (kw["module"] >> ident >> '(' >> ident_list >> ')' >> ';');

        statements           = -statement % ';';

        statement            = input_wires | output_wires | internal_wires | primitive | instance;

        input_wires          = kw["input"] >> ident_list;

        output_wires         = kw["output"] >> ident_list;

        internal_wires       = kw["wire"] >> ident_list;

        primitive            = primitive_gate >> ident >> '(' >> ident_list >> ')';

        instance             = ident >> ident >> '(' >> connection_pair_list >> ')';

        connection_pair_list = connection_pair % ',';

        // NOTE subtle use of `operator%=` in the presence of a semantic action
        connection_pair     %= (qi::lit('.')[phx::bind(&found_smth)] >> ident
                >> '(' >> ident >> ')');

        ident_list           = ident % ',';
        ident                = (qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z_0-9"));

        primitive_gate       = qi::raw[kw[primitive_gate_]];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (module)(module_definition)(statements)(statement)
                (primitive)(primitive_gate)(instance)
                (output_wires)(input_wires)(input_wires)
                (connection_pair_list)(connection_pair)(ident_list)(ident)
            )
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> module;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> module_definition;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> statements;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> statement;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> primitive;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> primitive_gate;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> instance;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> output_wires;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> input_wires;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> internal_wires;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >(), Skipper> connection_pair_list;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(), Skipper> connection_pair;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), Skipper> ident_list;

    // lexemes
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> ident;
    struct primitive_gate_t : qi::symbols<char> {
        primitive_gate_t() { this->add("nand")("nor")("and")("or")("xor")("xnor")("buf")("not"); }
    } primitive_gate_;

    Skipper skipper;
};

#include <fstream>
int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("input.txt");
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    It f(ifs >> std::noskipws), l;

    bool ok = qi::parse(f, l, verilog_grammar<It>{});
    if (ok) 
        std::cout << "Parsed\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
void found_smth()
void found_smth()
Parsed
```

Or with debug information enabled (`BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG`):

```xml
<module>
  <try>module mymod (A, B);</try>
  <module_definition>
    <try>module mymod (A, B);</try>
    <ident>
      <try>mymod (A, B);\n\ninput</try>
      <success> (A, B);\n\ninput A, B</success>
      <attributes>[[m, y, m, o, d]]</attributes>
    </ident>
    <ident_list>
      <try>A, B);\n\ninput A, B;\n</try>
      <ident>
        <try>A, B);\n\ninput A, B;\n</try>
        <success>, B);\n\ninput A, B;\n\n</success>
        <attributes>[[A]]</attributes>
      </ident>
      <ident>
        <try>B);\n\ninput A, B;\n\nXO</try>
        <success>);\n\ninput A, B;\n\nXOR</success>
        <attributes>[[B]]</attributes>
      </ident>
      <success>);\n\ninput A, B;\n\nXOR</success>
      <attributes>[[[A], [B]]]</attributes>
    </ident_list>
    <success>\n\ninput A, B;\n\nXOR21</success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </module_definition>
  <statements>
    <try>\n\ninput A, B;\n\nXOR21</try>
    <statement>
      <try>\n\ninput A, B;\n\nXOR21</try>
      <input_wires>
        <try>\n\ninput A, B;\n\nXOR21</try>
        <input_wires>
          <try>\n\ninput A, B;\n\nXOR21</try>
          <ident_list>
            <try> A, B;\n\nXOR21 gatexo</try>
            <ident>
              <try>A, B;\n\nXOR21 gatexor</try>
              <success>, B;\n\nXOR21 gatexor5</success>
              <attributes>[[A]]</attributes>
            </ident>
            <ident>
              <try>B;\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (</try>
              <success>;\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.</success>
              <attributes>[[B]]</attributes>
            </ident>
            <success>;\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.</success>
            <attributes>[[[A], [B]]]</attributes>
          </ident_list>
          <success>;\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.</success>
          <attributes>[]</attributes>
        </input_wires>
        <success>;\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.</success>
        <attributes>[]</attributes>
      </input_wires>
      <success>;\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.</success>
      <attributes>[]</attributes>
    </statement>
    <statement>
      <try>\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.A</try>
      <input_wires>
        <try>\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.A</try>
        <input_wires>
          <try>\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.A</try>
          <fail/>
        </input_wires>
        <fail/>
      </input_wires>
      <output_wires>
        <try>\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.A</try>
        <fail/>
      </output_wires>
      <primitive>
        <try>\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.A</try>
        <primitive_gate>
          <try>XOR21 gatexor5 (.A(B</try>
          <fail/>
        </primitive_gate>
        <fail/>
      </primitive>
      <instance>
        <try>\n\nXOR21 gatexor5 (.A</try>
        <ident>
          <try>XOR21 gatexor5 (.A(B</try>
          <success> gatexor5 (.A(B) , .</success>
          <attributes>[[X, O, R, 2, 1]]</attributes>
        </ident>
        <ident>
          <try>gatexor5 (.A(B) , .C</try>
          <success> (.A(B) , .C(D));\nen</success>
          <attributes>[[g, a, t, e, x, o, r, 5]]</attributes>
        </ident>
        <connection_pair_list>
          <try>.A(B) , .C(D));\nendm</try>
          <connection_pair>
            <try>.A(B) , .C(D));\nendm</try>
            <ident>
              <try>A(B) , .C(D));\nendmo</try>
              <success>(B) , .C(D));\nendmod</success>
              <attributes>[[A]]</attributes>
            </ident>
            <ident>
              <try>B) , .C(D));\nendmodu</try>
              <success>) , .C(D));\nendmodul</success>
              <attributes>[[B]]</attributes>
            </ident>
            <success> , .C(D));\nendmodule</success>
            <attributes>[[[A], [B]]]</attributes>
          </connection_pair>
          <connection_pair>
            <try> .C(D));\nendmodule\n</try>
            <ident>
              <try>C(D));\nendmodule\n</try>
              <success>(D));\nendmodule\n</success>
              <attributes>[[C]]</attributes>
            </ident>
            <ident>
              <try>D));\nendmodule\n</try>
              <success>));\nendmodule\n</success>
              <attributes>[[D]]</attributes>
            </ident>
            <success>);\nendmodule\n</success>
            <attributes>[[[C], [D]]]</attributes>
          </connection_pair>
          <success>);\nendmodule\n</success>
          <attributes>[[[[A], [B]], [[C], [D]]]]</attributes>
        </connection_pair_list>
        <success>;\nendmodule\n</success>
        <attributes>[]</attributes>
      </instance>
      <success>;\nendmodule\n</success>
      <attributes>[]</attributes>
    </statement>
    <statement>
      <try>\nendmodule\n</try>
      <input_wires>
        <try>\nendmodule\n</try>
        <input_wires>
          <try>\nendmodule\n</try>
          <fail/>
        </input_wires>
        <fail/>
      </input_wires>
      <output_wires>
        <try>\nendmodule\n</try>
        <fail/>
      </output_wires>
      <primitive>
        <try>\nendmodule\n</try>
        <primitive_gate>
          <try>endmodule\n</try>
          <fail/>
        </primitive_gate>
        <fail/>
      </primitive>
      <instance>
        <try>\nendmodule\n</try>
        <ident>
          <try>endmodule\n</try>
          <success>\n</success>
          <attributes>[[e, n, d, m, o, d, u, l, e]]</attributes>
        </ident>
        <ident>
          <try></try>
          <fail/>
        </ident>
        <fail/>
      </instance>
      <fail/>
    </statement>
    <success>\nendmodule\n</success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </statements>
  <success>\n</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</module>
```

---

¹ as long as one operand involved in the expression is from the Qi proto-expression domain

Comment: Oh, by the way. All I did was a code review, I didn't actually try to find the cause for your symptom (_"doesn't parse `'.'`"_). I'm assuming that cause was most like № 3. The whole "with a skipper" was a red herring, the result of [magical thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635994/boost-qi-rule-with-skipper-does-not-match-character/46636514#comment80221664_46635994) indeed. Luckily, next time you'll know how to debug your stuff, and it will tell you. In fact, you can use it now to verify that the missing (implicit) lexemes were the show-stopper.

Comment: Best response I have ever got! really appreciate you taking the time. Issue is solved :)

Comment: I forgot the link for keyword parsing. Edited (here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131162/how-to-parse-reserved-words-correctly-in-boost-spirit/20133011#20133011)

Comment: I've updated the post with the keyword-support and removing the phrase-parse. [Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yk7CULLwRkBMG2g9) this time.