# Boost Spirit Qi grammar adding to list inside skipper

Tags: boost-spirit-qi

Parsing these strings:

```cpp
int main(){
    for (const std::string input: std::vector<std::string> { 
            "module simple_in_n_out();endmodule;",
            "module simple_in_n_out(in_1);endmodule;",
            "module simple_in_n_out(in_1,in_2,in_3);endmodule;",
            })
    {
        parse_verilog_file(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Succeeds on first two inputs and push_back of first string, but fails when adding more strings to the vector:

```cpp
            std::string module_name;
            stringvec module_inputs;

            module_input_list %= tok.identifier[push_back(phoenix::ref(module_inputs), _1)] % qi::lit(',');
            module_input_list.name("module_input_list");
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(module_input_list);
            module_stmt
                %=   tok.module_ >> tok.identifier[phoenix::ref(module_name) = _1] 
                >> '(' >> -(module_input_list) >> ')'
                >> ';';
            module_stmt.name("module");
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(module_stmt);
```

Output looks like:

```
<module_stmt>
  <try>[module]</try>
  <module_input_list>
    <try>[)][;][endmodule][;]</try>
    <fail/>
  </module_input_list>
  <success>[endmodule][;]</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</module_stmt>
<module_stmt>
  <try>[endmodule][;]</try>
  <fail/>
</module_stmt>
TODO: put the module together now
<module_stmt>
  <try></try>
  <fail/>
</module_stmt>
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
-------------------------
module name: simple_in_n_out
<module_stmt>
  <try>[module]</try>
  <module_input_list>
    <try>[in_1][)][;][endmodule][;]</try>
    <success>[)][;][endmodule][;]</success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </module_input_list>
  <success>[endmodule][;]</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</module_stmt>
<module_stmt>
  <try>[endmodule][;]</try>
  <fail/>
</module_stmt>
TODO: put the module together now
<module_stmt>
  <try></try>
  <fail/>
</module_stmt>
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
-------------------------
module name: simple_in_n_out
    module input: in_1
<module_stmt>
  <try>[module]</try>
  <module_input_list>
    <try>[in_1]</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </module_input_list>
  <fail/>
</module_stmt>
-------------------------
Parsing failed
-------------------------
```

Full code:

```cpp
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include "netlist/netlistlexer.h"
namespace verilog {
    using namespace boost::spirit;
    using boost::phoenix::val;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::string;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Grammar definition
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template <typename Iterator, typename Lexer>
    struct verilog_grammar
    : qi::grammar<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> >
    {
        template <typename TokenDef>
        verilog_grammar(TokenDef const& tok)
        : verilog_grammar::base_type(program)
        {
            using boost::spirit::_val;
            using phoenix::push_back;
            using qi::on_error;
            using qi::fail;
            using phoenix::construct;

            program
                =   +statement
                ;


            statement
                =   module_stmt
                |   end_module_stmt
                ;


            module_input_list %= tok.identifier[push_back(phoenix::ref(module_inputs), _1)] % qi::lit(',');
            module_input_list.name("module_input_list");
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(module_input_list);
            module_stmt
                %=   tok.module_ >> tok.identifier[phoenix::ref(module_name) = _1] 
                >> '(' >> -(module_input_list) >> ')'
                >> ';';
            module_stmt.name("module");
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(module_stmt);
            end_module_stmt
                =   (tok.endmodule_ >> ';' | tok.endmodule_)[
                    std::cout << val("TODO: put the module together now") << "\n"
                ];
            end_module_stmt.name("end_module_stmt");

            on_error<fail>
            (
                program
            , std::cout
                    << val("Error! Expecting ")
                    << _4                               // what failed?
                    << val(" here: \"")
                    << construct<std::string>(_3, _2)   // iterators to error-pos, end
                    << val("\"")
                    << std::endl
            );
        }

        std::string module_name;
        stringvec module_inputs;
        typedef boost::variant<unsigned int, std::string> expression_type;
        typedef boost::fusion::vector<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> fustring;

        qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > program, statement;
        qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > module_stmt;
        qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > module_input_list;
        qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > end_module_stmt;
    };
} // end verilog namespace

void parse_verilog_file(std::string str){
    typedef std::string::iterator base_iterator_type;
    using namespace boost::spirit;
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<
        base_iterator_type, boost::mpl::vector<unsigned int, std::string>
    > token_type;
     typedef lex::lexertl::lexer<token_type> lexer_type;
     typedef verilog::verilog_tokens<lexer_type> verilog_tokens;
     typedef verilog_tokens::iterator_type iterator_type;
     typedef verilog::verilog_grammar<iterator_type, verilog_tokens::lexer_def> verilog_grammar;
     verilog_tokens tokens;                         // Our lexer
     verilog_grammar calc(tokens);                  // Our parser

     std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
     iterator_type iter = tokens.begin(it, str.end());
     iterator_type end = tokens.end();
     bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, qi::in_state("WS")[tokens.self]);

     if (r && iter == end)
     {
         std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
         std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
         std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
         std::cout << "module name: " << calc.module_name << "\n";
         for (const std::string i: calc.module_inputs){
             std::cout << "    module input: " << i << "\n";
         }
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
         std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
         std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
     }

}

int main(){
    for (const std::string input: std::vector<std::string> { 
            "module simple_in_n_out();endmodule;",
            "module simple_in_n_out(in_1);endmodule;",
            "module simple_in_n_out(in_1,in_2,in_3);endmodule;",
            })
    {
        parse_verilog_file(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

netlist/netlistlexer.h:

```cpp
#ifndef NETLISTLEXER_H
#define NETLISTLEXER_H
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
typedef std::vector<std::string> stringvec;
namespace verilog {
    using namespace boost::spirit;
    using boost::phoenix::val;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::string;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Token definition
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template <typename Lexer>
    struct verilog_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer>
    {
        verilog_tokens()
        {
            // define the tokens to match
            identifier = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*";
            logic_op = "[\\&\\|]";
            constant = "[0-9]+";
            module_ = "module";
            assign_ = "assign";
            endmodule_ = "endmodule";
            wire_ = "wire";
            input_ = "input";
            output_ = "output";
            inout_ = "inout";
            reg_ = "reg";
            begin_ = "begin";
            end_ = "end";
            always_ = "always";
            if_ = "if";
            else_ = "else";
            parameter_ = "parameter";

            // associate the tokens and the token set with the lexer
            this->self = lex::token_def<>('(') | ')' | '{' | '}' | '=' | '[' | ']' | ';' | constant | logic_op;
            this->self += if_ | else_ | begin_ | end_ | always_ | reg_;
            this->self += module_ | endmodule_ | assign_ | wire_ | input_ | output_ | inout_;
            this->self += parameter_;
            this->self += identifier;

            // define the whitespace to ignore (spaces, tabs, newlines and C-style
            // comments)
            this->self("WS")
                =   lex::token_def<>("[ \\t\\n]+")
                |   "\\/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^/*][^*]*\\*+)*\\/"
                |   "\\/\\/[^\\r\\n\\f]*"
                |   "\\(\\*[^*]*\\*\\)"
                ;
        }

        // these tokens have no attribute
        lex::token_def<lex::omit> if_, else_, begin_, end_, endmodule_;

        // these tokens expose the iterator_range of the matched input sequence
        lex::token_def<> always_, reg_;
        lex::token_def<> module_, assign_, wire_, input_, output_, inout_;
        lex::token_def<> parameter_;

        // The following two tokens have an associated attribute type, 'identifier'
        // carries a string (the identifier name) and 'constant' carries the
        // matched integer value.
        //
        // Note: any token attribute type explicitly specified in a token_def<>
        //       declaration needs to be listed during token type definition as
        //       well (see the typedef for the token_type below).
        //
        // The conversion of the matched input to an instance of this type occurs
        // once (on first access), which makes token attributes as efficient as
        // possible. Moreover, token instances are constructed once by the lexer
        // library. From this point on tokens are passed by reference only,
        // avoiding them being copied around.
        lex::token_def<std::string> identifier;
        lex::token_def<unsigned int> constant;
        lex::token_def<std::string> logic_op;
    };
} // end verilog namespace
#endif // NETLISTLEXER_H
```

Comment: There's a reason I'm not having the grammar output the fusion adapted struct: I'm handling a case where people put the statements out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I had to cut through the fog of Spirit Lex¹ and some quirks indicating that you might not be working with a standards-comforming compiler².

[When I did](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gr6mGP3aedx5PhPI), I noticed that the actual grammar doesn't use attribute propagation, instead using ad-hoc Semantic Actions to extract some information³.

I'm already on record that I think Spirit shines for quick prototyping *when you find the sweet-spot*. Manual AST building based on semantic actions is not where that spot lies IMO.

As a final subtle clue I noticed that you "uselessly" include `recursive_variant.hpp` - which made me think you were actually *hoping* to use automatic attribute propagation with a recursive AST?

---

### First Ideas

Let's use the `module_stmt` as an example. Instead of "abitrarily side-effecting" into the `module_name` and `module_inputs` parser member variables, let's use an AST type:

```cpp
namespace AST {
    using identifiers = stringvec;

    struct module {
        std::string name;
        identifiers inputs;
    };
}
```

Adapt it for automatic propagation:

```cpp
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::module, name, inputs)
```

And rely on that instead:

```cpp
module_input_list = tok.identifier % ',';
module_stmt       
     = tok.module_ >> tok.identifier 
    >> '(' >> -module_input_list >> ')' >> ';'
    >> tok.endmodule_ >> (';' | qi::eoi)
    ;
```

> Note: I had to fix the `module_` token definition to `lex::omit`
>
> Note how I included `endmodule_` into the rule because that's the natural thing to do. Any nested (recursive) rules (like nested `statements` can just naturally go there and either synthesize into members of `AST::module`

The rule declarations can be:

```cpp
qi::rule<Iterator, AST::module(),      Skipper> module_stmt;
qi::rule<Iterator, AST::identifiers(), Skipper> module_input_list;
```

### Tying it together

Of course, now the top-level rules have *no* attributes declared, so the `AST::module` instance that is magically synthesized just vanishes. That's unfortunate, but very easy to fix. Extending our AST types:

```cpp
namespace AST {
    using identifiers = stringvec;

    struct module {
        std::string name;
        identifiers inputs;
    };

    using statement = boost::make_recursive_variant<
        module // module_stmt
    >::type;

    using statements = std::vector<statement>;

    struct program {
        statements body;
    };
}
```

This rather simplistic take on a Verilog program will do. We extend the rules:

```cpp
qi::rule<Iterator, AST::program(),     Skipper> program;
qi::rule<Iterator, AST::statements(),  Skipper> statements;
qi::rule<Iterator, AST::statement(),   Skipper> statement;
qi::rule<Iterator, AST::module(),      Skipper> module_stmt;
qi::rule<Iterator, AST::identifiers(), Skipper> module_input_list;
```

You will note the pattern of matching the rules to their corresponding AST nodes. The rules themselves don't change:

```cpp
program            = statements;
statements         = +statement;
statement          = module_stmt;

module_input_list = tok.identifier % ',';
module_stmt       
     = tok.module_ >> tok.identifier 
    >> '(' >> -module_input_list >> ')' >> ';'
    >> tok.endmodule_ >> (';' | qi::eoi)
    ;
```

> Note: I introduced the `statements` for consistency, and it also sidesteps a pitfall with propagating into single-element adapted fusion sequences⁴

Now we can pass a `AST::program` attribute to the parser invocation:

```cpp
AST::program program;
if (qi::parse(iter, end, calc, program)) {
    for (auto& stmt : program.body) {
        if (auto* module = boost::get<AST::module>(&stmt)) {
            std::cout << "module name: " << module->name << "\n";
            for (std::string const& i : module->inputs) {
                std::cout << "    module input: " << i << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will print the same output as expected:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gr6mGP3aedx5PhPI)</kbd>**

```cpp
-------------------------
module simple_in_n_out();endmodule;
Parsing succeeded
module name: simple_in_n_out
-------------------------
-------------------------
module simple_in_n_out(in_1);endmodule;
Parsing succeeded
module name: simple_in_n_out
    module input: in_1
-------------------------
-------------------------
module simple_in_n_out(in_1,in_2,in_3);endmodule;
Parsing failed
-------------------------
```

### Debugging the failure

Uncommenting `#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` shows what the problem is:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/S5TkSiUpJruLr2nL)</kbd>**

```xml
<program>
  <try>[module]</try>
  <statements>
    <try>[module]</try>
    <statement>
      <try>[module]</try>
      <module_stmt>
        <try>[module]</try>
        <module_input_list>
          <try>[in_1]</try>
          <success></success>
          <attributes>[[[i, n, _, 1]]]</attributes>
        </module_input_list>
        <fail/>
      </module_stmt>
      <fail/>
    </statement>
    <fail/>
  </statements>
  <fail/>
</program>
```

The problem isn't with any of the rules! It's with `','` not matching. Quick glance at the tokens tells us why: there's no token that matches the comma... Adding it in a hurry:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b9jYhf0VxnW3IIAY)</kbd>**

```
-------------------------
module simple_in_n_out();endmodule;
Parsing succeeded
module name: simple_in_n_out
-------------------------
-------------------------
module simple_in_n_out(in_1);endmodule;
Parsing succeeded
module name: simple_in_n_out
    module input: in_1
-------------------------
-------------------------
module simple_in_n_out(in_1,in_2,in_3);endmodule;
Parsing succeeded
module name: simple_in_n_out
    module input: in_1
    module input: in_2
    module input: in_3
-------------------------
```

### BONUS

However, that "problem" kinda highlights another cost factor due to the lexer (notice the other issue with `module_` token I papered over earlier). So here's the whole thing without the Lex overhead, without Phoenix overhead, in a fraction of the code, with full AST propagation:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/38r7cgti9GynMWh5)</kbd>**

```cpp
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip> // std::quoted
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace AST {
    using identifier = std::string;
    using identifiers = std::vector<identifier>;

    struct module {
        identifier name;
        identifiers inputs;
    };

    using statement = boost::variant<module>;
    using statements = std::vector<statement>;

    struct program {
        statements body;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::module, name, inputs)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::program, body)

namespace verilog {
    template <typename Iterator> struct verilog_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, AST::program()> {

        verilog_grammar() : verilog_grammar::base_type(start) {
            auto kw = [](auto p) { return qi::copy(qi::lexeme[qi::no_case[p] >> !(qi::alnum|'_') ]); };

            start      = qi::skip(skipper.alias()) [ program ];
            program    = statements > qi::eoi;
            statements = -statement % ';';
            statement  = module_stmt.alias();

            module_input_list = identifier % ',';
            module_stmt       
                 = kw("module") >> identifier 
                >> '(' >> -module_input_list >> ')' >> ';'
                >> kw("endmodule")
                ;

            // lexemes
            identifier = qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");

            skipper = qi::char_(" \t\r\n") // added \r for consistency
                | "//" >> *~qi::char_("\r\n\f") 
                | "/*" >> *(qi::char_ - "*/") >> "*/"
                | "(*" >> *(qi::char_ - "*)") >> "*)"
                ;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((program)(statements)(statement)(module_stmt)(module_input_list)(identifier));
        }

      private:
        using Skipper = qi::rule<Iterator>;

        qi::rule<Iterator, AST::program()> start;
        Skipper skipper;

        qi::rule<Iterator, AST::program(),     Skipper> program;
        qi::rule<Iterator, AST::statements(),  Skipper> statements;
        qi::rule<Iterator, AST::statement(),   Skipper> statement;
        qi::rule<Iterator, AST::module(),      Skipper> module_stmt;
        qi::rule<Iterator, AST::identifiers(), Skipper> module_input_list;

        // lexemes (formerly "tokens")
        qi::rule<Iterator, AST::identifier()> identifier;
    };
} // end verilog namespace

AST::program parse_verilog_file(std::string const& str) {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator;
    static const verilog::verilog_grammar<iterator> grammar; // Our parser, now stateless

    try {
        AST::program program;
        parse(str.begin(), str.end(), grammar, program);
        return program;
    } catch(qi::expectation_failure<iterator> const& ef) {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "Parsing failed: expected " << ef.what_ << " at " << std::quoted(std::string(ef.first, ef.last));
        throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
    }
}

int main() {
    for (const std::string input : std::vector<std::string>{
             "module simple_in_n_out();endmodule;",
             "module simple_in_n_out(in_1);endmodule;",
             "module simple_in_n_out(in_1,in_2,in_3);endmodule;",
             "module a();endmodule",
             "module a();endmodule;oops",
         })
    try {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << std::quoted(input) << "\n";

        for (auto const& stmt : parse_verilog_file(input).body) {
            if (auto* module = boost::get<AST::module>(&stmt)) {
                std::cout << "module name: " << module->name << "\n";
                for (std::string const& i : module->inputs) {
                    std::cout << "    module input: " << i << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Printing

```
-------------------------
"module simple_in_n_out();endmodule;"
module name: simple_in_n_out
-------------------------
"module simple_in_n_out(in_1);endmodule;"
module name: simple_in_n_out
    module input: in_1
-------------------------
"module simple_in_n_out(in_1,in_2,in_3);endmodule;"
module name: simple_in_n_out
    module input: in_1
    module input: in_2
    module input: in_3
-------------------------
"module a();endmodule"
module name: a
-------------------------
"module a();endmodule;oops"
Parsing failed: expected <eoi> at "oops"
```

Notable improvements:

- Correct parsing of "keyword boundaries" (that's what the `kw()` helper is about). This means that if you have an identifier that *begins* with something that could be a keyword, it will not be falsely tokenized as that keyword (something that would happen with the original Lex-based approach)
- Keywords are trivially case-insensitive (`qi::no_case[]`) - just for the sake of demo
- The skipper is so much simpler to specify, and readable at the same time
- Something that I already did in the Lex-based versions in this answer: the skipper is encapsulated in the grammar now. I'm of the opinion that a skipper should only be user-suppliable if the user may actually need to change it. In 99% of the cases the skipper is tightly coupled to the parser and using the wrong one would break the grammar regardless.

  As a bonus, invocation becomes much cleaner:

```cpp
    AST::program program;
    parse(str.begin(), str.end(), grammar, program);
    return program;
```

- Tieing into that notice how I simplified the `parse_verilog_file` function to ... be a function (returning the result), separating producing and handling the result

```cpp
    AST::program parse_verilog_file(std::string const& str) {
        typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator;
        static const verilog::verilog_grammar<iterator> grammar; // Our parser, now stateless

        try {
            AST::program program;
            parse(str.begin(), str.end(), grammar, program);
            return program;
        } catch(qi::expectation_failure<iterator> const& ef) {
            std::ostringstream msg;
            msg << "Parsing failed: expected " << ef.what_ << " at " << std::quoted(std::string(ef.first, ef.last));
            throw std::runtime_error(msg.str());
        }
    }
```

- That in turn shows a simplified error-handling by just catching the exception
- Which in turn I use to replace the `iter!=end` check by just an other expectation point:

```cpp
    program    = statements > qi::eoi;
```

This, in combination with

```cpp
    statements = -statement % ';';
```

Makes it so that ``` ';`` is required between statements, but not at the end of the program (which I _guess_ is what you wanted to convey with the old ```endmodule` rule)

> Notice as well that `-statement % ';'` makes it so that empty statements are acceptable. If that's not what you wanted, drop the `'-`
>
> Note that the added test cases test and demonstrate the error detection/reporting for this logic (`"module a();endmodule;oops"` results in `Parsing failed: expected <eoi> at "oops"`)

- Any "tokens" like "identifier" are now "lexeme" rules, in that they do not obey the skipper⁵ The debug support now seemlessly includes those tokens the way you'd expect: **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1eZXqSVk3HH6YGct)</kbd>**

  ```xml
  <module_input_list>
    <try>in_1,in_2,in_3);endm</try>
    <identifier>
      <try>in_1,in_2,in_3);endm</try>
      <success>,in_2,in_3);endmodul</success>
      <attributes>[[i, n, _, 1]]</attributes>
    </identifier>
    <identifier>
      <try>in_2,in_3);endmodule</try>
      <success>,in_3);endmodule;oop</success>
      <attributes>[[i, n, _, 2]]</attributes>
    </identifier>
    <identifier>
      <try>in_3);endmodule;oops</try>
      <success>);endmodule;oops</success>
      <attributes>[[i, n, _, 3]]</attributes>
    </identifier>
    <success>);endmodule;oops</success>
    <attributes>[[[i, n, _, 1], [i, n, _, 2], [i, n, _, 3]]]</attributes>
  </module_input_list>
  ```
- Oh, the code is significantly shorter while doing more: down from 211 to 112 lines of code (-47%)
- It compiles significantly faster (12.1s down from  19.7s on my system)
- Oh, given the current features, it can be further simplified: **<kbd>[This clocks in at 90 LoC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bllmYR7gOmU25tjI)</kbd>**. However I would instead encourage at improving the features of the grammar, look e.g. here

  - [Boost.Qi rule with skipper does not match '.' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635994/boost-qi-rule-with-skipper-does-not-match-character/46636514#46636514) which also shows a Verilog parser, and has more info on the `kw()` facility
  - [cannot get boost::spirit parser&lexer working for token types other than std::string or int or double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191531/cannot-get-boostspirit-parserlexer-working-for-token-types-other-than-stdst/47232006#47232006) which parses modules, disciplines, natures in a similar Verilog syntax and uses Lex as well

---

¹ Anecdotally: "nobody uses that anymore". I'm not saying that because I don't know it ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+qi+lex)), and I'm not alone. From [this 2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232006/85371):

> using Lex makes most of the sweet-spot disappear since all "highlevel" parsers (like real_parser, [u]int_parser) are out the window. The Spirit devs are on record they prefer not to use Lex. Moreover, Spirit X3 doesn't have Lex support anymore.

² My guess MSVC, not fully up-to-date? The main culprit being ambiguous names because you uses `using namespace`.

³ [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

⁴ see many answers on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+spirit+single-element

⁵ see perhaps [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965) for my go-to description of how skippers, rule declarations and lexemes interact

Comment: I intentionally went with the ad-hoc semantic actions rather than the ast or the fusion-adapt-struct, simply because the end result desired was separate lists ... but I can do that later and just do the AST things you show here ... at the very least for sheer appreciation of all your hard work!! Thank you!!

Comment: I figure you have to balance how much more complicated the work is going to be against what (performance?) gain you think you'll have. If you know what you need, you _might_ be able to find a shortcut. It might just be less straight-forward, making it harder to achieve.